# Unable to align the radio buttons with text

Tags: jquery, html, css

I intend to align the `radio` buttons with the text side by side.
I've managed to align the `radio` buttons vertically in a straight line, but I'm now unable to keep the `radio` buttons and text side by side.

**Code**

```js
var allQuestions = [{
    question: "Who is the Prime Minister of the United Kingdom?",
    choices: ["David Cameron", "Gordon Brown", "Winston Churchill"],
    correctAnswer: 0
  },

  {
    question: "Who is the Prime Minister of India?",
    choices: ["Rahul Gandhi", "Arvind Kejrival", "Narendra Damodardas Modi"],
    correctAnswer: 2
  },

  {
    question: "Who is the Prime Minister of America?",
    choices: ["Donald Trump", "Barack Obama", "Hilary Clinton"],
    correctAnswer: 1
  },

  {
    question: " Who averaged one patent for every three weeks of his life?",
    choices: ["Thomas Edison", "Tesla", "Einstein"],
    correctAnswer: 0
  },

  {
    question: "What continent is cut into two fairly equal halves by the Tropic of Capricorn?",
    choices: ["Africa", "South America", "Australia"],
    correctAnswer: 2
  },

  {
    question: "What explorer introduced pigs to North America?",
    choices: ["Christopher Columbus", "Galileo", "Mussorie"],
    correctAnswer: 0
  },

  {
    question: "What F-word is defined in physics as a “nuclear reaction in which nuclei combine to form more massive nuclei”? ",
    choices: ["Furnace", "Fusion", "Fission"],
    correctAnswer: 1
  },

  {
    question: "What was the first planet to be discovered using the telescope, in 1781?",
    choices: ["Uranus", "Jupiter", "Mars"],
    correctAnswer: 0
  },

  {
    question: "Who is the chief minister of West Bengal, India?",
    choices: ["Buddhadev Bhattacharya", "Jyoti Basu", "Mamta Banerjee"],
    correctAnswer: 2
  },

  {
    question: "Which is the fastest growing religion in the world?",
    choices: ["Islam", "Christianity", "Hinduism"],
    correctAnswer: 0
  }
  /*
   {
    question: "Who is the Prime Minister of America?",
    choices: ["Donald Trump","Barack Obama","Hilary Clinton"],
    correctAnswer:1
   },

   {
    question: "Who is the Prime Minister of America?",
    choices: ["Donald Trump","Barack Obama","Hilary Clinton"],
    correctAnswer:1
   },

   {
    question: "Who is the Prime Minister of America?",
    choices: ["Donald Trump","Barack Obama","Hilary Clinton"],
    correctAnswer:1
   },

   {
    question: "Who is the Prime Minister of America?",
    choices: ["Donald Trump","Barack Obama","Hilary Clinton"],
    correctAnswer:1
   },

   {
    question: "Who is the Prime Minister of America?",
    choices: ["Donald Trump","Barack Obama","Hilary Clinton"],
    correctAnswer:1
   } */
];


$(document).ready(function() {
  var currentquestion = 0;
  var correctAnswers = 0;

  $(function() {
    $("#progressbar").progressbar({
      value: 0
    });
  });

  $('#question').html(allQuestions[currentquestion].question);
  $('label[for=option0]').html(allQuestions[currentquestion].choices[0] + "<br/>");
  $('label[for=option1]').html(allQuestions[currentquestion].choices[1] + "<br/>");
  $('label[for=option2]').html(allQuestions[currentquestion].choices[2] + "<br/>");

  $("#next").click(function() {
    if ($("input[name=option]:checked").val() == allQuestions[currentquestion].correctAnswer) {
      correctAnswers++;
    };
    currentquestion++;
    $(function() {
      $("#progressbar").progressbar({
        value: currentquestion * (allQuestions.length),
      });
    });
    if (currentquestion < allQuestions.length) {
      $('#question').html(allQuestions[currentquestion].question);
      $('label[for=option0]').html(allQuestions[currentquestion].choices[0] + "<br/>");
      $('label[for=option1]').html(allQuestions[currentquestion].choices[1] + "<br/>");
      $('label[for=option2]').html(allQuestions[currentquestion].choices[2] + "<br/>");
      if (currentquestion == allQuestions.length - 1) {
        $('#next').html("Submit");
        //$('#next').off("click");
        $('#next').click(function() {
          // if($("input[name=option]:checked").val()==allQuestions[currentquestion].correctAnswer){
          //  correctAnswers++;
          // };
          // alert(correctAnswers);
          alert("Your Score is " + correctAnswers + " out of " + currentquestion + " and your percentage is " + (correctAnswers * 100 / (currentquestion)) + "%");
        });

      }

    };
  });
});
```

```css
.ui-widget-header {
  background-image: none !important;
  background-color: #FF7860 !important; //Any colour can go here
}
label {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}
/*input[name="option"] {
  float:left;
}*/

#progressbar {
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 20px;
  float: none;
  width: 50%;
  /*height: 100%;*/
}
#container {
  text-align: center;
}
span {
  margin: 5em;
  padding: 3em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <h3 id="question"></h3>
  <form id="form">
    <input type="radio" name="option" value="0" id="option0" checked>
    <label for='option0'>
      <br/>
    </label>
    <input type="radio" name="option" value="1" id="option1">
    <label for='option1'>
      <br/>
    </label>
    <input type="radio" name="option" value="2" id="option2">
    <label for='option2'>
      <br/>
    </label>
  </form>

  <br/>
  <a href="#" id="next" class="button">Next</a>
  <br/>
  <div id="progressbar"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your `display:block` in your `label` to `inline-block` and remove the `<br />` outside the `<label>` in HTML, wrap `label/input` with a `div`

```js
var allQuestions = [{
    question: "Who is the Prime Minister of the United Kingdom?",
    choices: ["David Cameron", "Gordon Brown", "Winston Churchill"],
    correctAnswer: 0
  },

  {
    question: "Who is the Prime Minister of India?",
    choices: ["Rahul Gandhi", "Arvind Kejrival", "Narendra Damodardas Modi"],
    correctAnswer: 2
  },

  {
    question: "Who is the Prime Minister of America?",
    choices: ["Donald Trump", "Barack Obama", "Hilary Clinton"],
    correctAnswer: 1
  },

  {
    question: " Who averaged one patent for every three weeks of his life?",
    choices: ["Thomas Edison", "Tesla", "Einstein"],
    correctAnswer: 0
  },

  {
    question: "What continent is cut into two fairly equal halves by the Tropic of Capricorn?",
    choices: ["Africa", "South America", "Australia"],
    correctAnswer: 2
  },

  {
    question: "What explorer introduced pigs to North America?",
    choices: ["Christopher Columbus", "Galileo", "Mussorie"],
    correctAnswer: 0
  },

  {
    question: "What F-word is defined in physics as a “nuclear reaction in which nuclei combine to form more massive nuclei”? ",
    choices: ["Furnace", "Fusion", "Fission"],
    correctAnswer: 1
  },

  {
    question: "What was the first planet to be discovered using the telescope, in 1781?",
    choices: ["Uranus", "Jupiter", "Mars"],
    correctAnswer: 0
  },

  {
    question: "Who is the chief minister of West Bengal, India?",
    choices: ["Buddhadev Bhattacharya", "Jyoti Basu", "Mamta Banerjee"],
    correctAnswer: 2
  },

  {
    question: "Which is the fastest growing religion in the world?",
    choices: ["Islam", "Christianity", "Hinduism"],
    correctAnswer: 0
  }
  /*
   {
    question: "Who is the Prime Minister of America?",
    choices: ["Donald Trump","Barack Obama","Hilary Clinton"],
    correctAnswer:1
   },

   {
    question: "Who is the Prime Minister of America?",
    choices: ["Donald Trump","Barack Obama","Hilary Clinton"],
    correctAnswer:1
   },

   {
    question: "Who is the Prime Minister of America?",
    choices: ["Donald Trump","Barack Obama","Hilary Clinton"],
    correctAnswer:1
   },

   {
    question: "Who is the Prime Minister of America?",
    choices: ["Donald Trump","Barack Obama","Hilary Clinton"],
    correctAnswer:1
   },

   {
    question: "Who is the Prime Minister of America?",
    choices: ["Donald Trump","Barack Obama","Hilary Clinton"],
    correctAnswer:1
   } */
];


$(document).ready(function() {
  var currentquestion = 0;
  var correctAnswers = 0;

  $(function() {
    $("#progressbar").progressbar({
      value: 0
    });
  });

  $('#question').html(allQuestions[currentquestion].question);
  $('label[for=option0]').html(allQuestions[currentquestion].choices[0] + "<br/>");
  $('label[for=option1]').html(allQuestions[currentquestion].choices[1] + "<br/>");
  $('label[for=option2]').html(allQuestions[currentquestion].choices[2] + "<br/>");

  $("#next").click(function() {
    if ($("input[name=option]:checked").val() == allQuestions[currentquestion].correctAnswer) {
      correctAnswers++;
    };
    currentquestion++;
    $(function() {
      $("#progressbar").progressbar({
        value: currentquestion * (allQuestions.length),
      });
    });
    if (currentquestion < allQuestions.length) {
      $('#question').html(allQuestions[currentquestion].question);
      $('label[for=option0]').html(allQuestions[currentquestion].choices[0] + "<br/>");
      $('label[for=option1]').html(allQuestions[currentquestion].choices[1] + "<br/>");
      $('label[for=option2]').html(allQuestions[currentquestion].choices[2] + "<br/>");
      if (currentquestion == allQuestions.length - 1) {
        $('#next').html("Submit");
        //$('#next').off("click");
        $('#next').click(function() {
          // if($("input[name=option]:checked").val()==allQuestions[currentquestion].correctAnswer){
          //  correctAnswers++;
          // };
          // alert(correctAnswers);
          alert("Your Score is " + correctAnswers + " out of " + currentquestion + " and your percentage is " + (correctAnswers * 100 / (currentquestion)) + "%");
        });

      }

    };
  });
});
```

```css
.ui-widget-header {
  background-image: none !important;
  background-color: #FF7860 !important;
}
h3, #next {
  text-align: center;
  display:block
}
#form div {
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 205px
}
label {
  display: inline-block;
}
input[name^="option"] {
  float: left;
}
#progressbar {
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 20px;
  float: none;
  width: 50%;
  /*height: 100%;*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <h3 id="question"></h3>
  <form id="form">
    <div>
      <input type="radio" name="option" value="0" id="option0" checked>
      <label for='option0'></label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="radio" name="option" value="1" id="option1">
      <label for='option1'></label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="radio" name="option" value="2" id="option2">
      <label for='option2'></label>
    </div>
  </form>

  <br/>
  <a href="#" id="next" class="button">Next</a>
  <br/>
  <div id="progressbar"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think I couldn't explain my problem well enough..I meant to have the three options in three separate lines..

Comment: tried that..but it makes the radio buttons misaligned..I want to have the radio buttons in a straight line, directly one above the other

Comment: i'm gonna update the answer, but next time add all the requirements in your initial question for a proper answer right away

Answer (score 0):

Just set your CSS for label to display "inline-block":

**CSS**

```
    label{
      display: inline-block;
      text-align: center;
    }
```

**HTML**

```
    <form id="form">
          <label for='option0'></label><input type="radio" name="option" value="0" id="option0" checked><br />
          <label for='option1'></label><input type="radio" name="option" value="1" id="option1"><br />
          <label for='option2'></label><input type="radio" name="option" value="2" id="option2"><br />
```

**EDIT**

So, both answers don't solve the problem...

What you have to do is that :

1) Set you CSS for label :

```
label{   display: inline-block; }
```

2) Create a new class for radio buttons :

```
 .rad_in {
   position: absolute;
   left : 25%;
 }
```

3) And then your html goes like this (with the radio button class) :

> ```
>       <form id="form">
>           <input class="rad_in" type="radio" name="option" value="0" id="option0" checked><label for='option0'></label><br />
>           <input class="rad_in" type="radio" name="option" value="1" id="option1"><label for='option1'></label><br />
>           <input class="rad_in" type="radio" name="option" value="2" id="option2"><label for='option2'></label><br />
>         </form>
> ```

Here is the fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/8fv3cnc6/

Comment: @ Adrien just undeleted it

Answer (score 0):

See my edited answer and the fiddle :

```
.rad_in {
  position: absolute;
  left : 25%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8fv3cnc6/

PS: Sorry, i had to post another answer since I can't comment...